# Protractor addMockModule additional arguments not working?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end, ngmocke2e

This seems so, so easy, but I can't figure out why this simple code doesn't work.

I am adding a mock module to mock my API backend in my Angular E2E tests. I'm using Protractor 1.6.0. I need to pass additional arguments to the mocked module, which, according to the Protractor docs, is possible by just sending them as additional arguments. However, my function claims it has no arguments...

```
var mock = function() {
  // This is undefined and arguments.length is 0....why???
  var env = arguments[0];
  var mocks = angular.module('mocks.login', ['MyApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
  mocks.run(function($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET(env.apiBase + '/companies').respond([]);
  });
};

browser.addMockModule('mocks.login', mock, {apiBase: ""});
```

If it matters, I'm doing this in my Protractor config file in an onPrepare, as I'm trying to mock the API calls used during a user's login. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to move your code from `onPrepare` in Protractor config to `beforeEach` in your test suite?

Answer (score 0):

Appearantely the args should be passed as array.
This is how it worked for me:

```
        var test =  {
            val1: 'val1',
            val2: 'val2'
        };
       browser.addMockModule('mockModule', function( args) {
            angular.module('mockModule', [])
                .value('TEST', args[0]);

        }, [test]);
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
var mock = function(args) {
    // args.apiBase should be available here
    var env = args;
    var mocks = angular.module('mocks.login', ['MyApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
    mocks.run(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenGET(env.apiBase + '/companies').respond([]);
    });
};

browser.addMockModule('mocks.login', mock, {apiBase: ""});
```