# Using variables in httpBackend mock function

Tags: angularjs, mocking, protractor, ngmocke2e

I want to be able to define a variable and then use said variable in the respond() method inside the module.run() function. I have this code inside my it():

```
    var testValue=randomValue(); // suffice to say, a random value generator
    var httpBackendMock = function() {
        angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['ngMockE2E', 'name.of.app'])
            .run(function($httpBackend) {
                $httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*\/api\/data/).respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
                    return [200, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> \
                    <data>'+testValue+'</data>', {}];
                });
....
```

But the `testValue` variable defined above the `httpBackendMock` object isn't visible inside the run() function at all, but will be 'undefined'.

My understanding is that 'var' defined variables in JS are available to inner-scoped code, but that's not happening here. Is there some way to get variables to work inside there?

Comment: `httpBackendMock` isn't an object. It is a function. Please, show what happens with it. If it is executed with `browser.executeScript(httpBackendMock)`, this obviously won't work, because outer function scope runs in Node and inner function scope runs in browser.

Comment: @estus It is from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend . I tagged it with ngmocke2e because I probably need people who are familiar with that framework.

Comment: There's no mention of `httpBackendMock` function in the link you've posted. Please, show how this function is being called.

Comment: `browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock);`
Example from http://product.moveline.com/testing-angular-apps-end-to-end-with-protractor.html#beyond-the-basics

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code

```
var testValue=randomValue();
```

is executed in Node. And this piece of code

```
function() {
    angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['ngMockE2E', 'name.of.app'])
    ...
}
```

is converted to string, passed to client side and executed in browser.

Outer function scope is not available in inner function, this explains why `testValue` is `undefined` in `httpBackendMock` function, and it will throw an error if `httpBackendMock` function uses strict mode.

Additional data can be passed through `executeScript` and `addMockModule` extra arguments, which will be available on client side.

As it is shown [in documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Browser.prototype.addMockModule), the arguments after the first two are passed to the browser.

It should be something like

```
var httpBackendMock = function(testValue) {
    angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['ngMockE2E', 'name.of.app'])
    ...
}
...
var testValue=randomValue();
browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock, testValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to pass in a nested array of values and add an argument to the function signature of the mockmodule object.

```
var httpBackendMock = function(args) {
    var isFoo=args[0];
    var isBar=args[1];
...
browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock, [['foo','bar']]);
```

Found the answer at:
[Protractor addMockModule additional arguments not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883577/protractor-addmockmodule-additional-arguments-not-working)